# Passing arrays into testclass constructors

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I need to pass a 1d array that isn't defined in a method.

I need to create a testclass then make the arrays myself.

I'm just not sure about the syntax.

Example, here's my company class:

```
public class Company
{
String name;
String address;
Employee employeeList[] = new Employee[3];

public Company (String name, String address ,
                     Employee employeeList, String jobTitle )
{
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
}
public void printDetails()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i>employeeList.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(" The companys name is " + name);
            System.out.println(" The Companys Address is "+ address);
            System.out.println("The List of employees are " + employeeList[i].name);
            System.out.println("The Titles of These Employees are " + employeeList[i].jobTitle);
        }
    }
}
```

But my testclass is where the problem lies.

Where do I go from here? Do do I put `arrays(employees)` into it?

```
public class TestCompany
{
public static void main(String[] args)

{                                                                        employees?
Company hungryBear = new Company("hungryBear ", "Those weird apartments ",//////   );
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you say this is a 2d array? I only see one dimension.

Comment: Can you provide more detail? What is suppose to go into the 2d array? When you say that it "isn't defined in a method", what do you mean? Are you trying to send in an array of employees and then iterate though it? The more you can provide, the better

Comment: the for loop where it says `i > employeeList.length` probably should say `i < employeeList.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Company (String name, String address ,
                     Employee employeeList, String jobTitle )
```

Should be:

```
public Company (String name, String address ,
                     Employee []employeeList, String jobTitle )
```

Right now, you're not passing an array to your method, your passing an instance.  You need to tell Java that you're passing an array.

Editted with new knowledge of the employee class...

Also, you will need to build the array in your main function before you pass it.  Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){                                                                        
    Employee [] employeeList = {
        new Employee("Samuel T. Anders", "Player, Caprica Buccaneers"),
        new Employee("William Adama", "Commander, Battlestar Galactica")
    };

    Company hungryBear = new Company("hungryBear ", "Those weird apartments ", employeeList);
}
```

Not really sure this answers your question, but maybe this will help you with the syntax of array passing a little.

Another edit, another way to initialize an array:

```
Empolyee [] employeeList = new Employee[2];
employeeList[0] = new Employee("Samuel T. Anders", "Player, Caprica Buccaneers");
employeeList[1] = new Employee("William Adama", "Commander, Battlestar Galactica");
```

Comment: Editted the answer.  You can also initialize the array with the number of values you have and then set each cell individually.

Answer (score 0):

```
Empolyee [] employeeList = new Employee[2];


for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  employeeList[i] = input.next();
}
```